# Adding Custom Properties

Tags: c#, user-controls, properties

I have created a user control, and now I want to add custom properties to it so they will appear in the Properties toolbar in Vis. Studio. How can this be done?

My custom property will be: "Animation Type" with options "Fade | Blink | Scroll | Blend"

thank you

Comment: It amazes me that you didn't take the few minutes necessary to try this yourself. Did you really not realize there is no magic here, that they are normal properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer automatically reads properties of the class and adds them to the properties view. So all you need to do is to create the property with a public getter and setter

```
public AnimationType AnimationType { get; set; }
```

There are extra attributes you can apply to the property, for example [DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) or [EditorBrowsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx), that change how it appears in the properties view. All the relevant  attributes are in the [System.ComponentModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.aspx) namespace.